# MS Build Error 3181- Problem with referenced assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, assemblies

imagine the following scenario:

- Assembly "Foo.dll" references the ADOX-Library (Microsoft ADO Ext. 2.8 for DDL and Security) which was added as Interop.ADOX.dll in the bin-directory by VS 2010. "Local copy" of this reference was set to true, too.
- Assembly "Bar.exe" references both Foo.dll and additionally the ADOX-Library because some functionality from it is needed in Bar.exe
- Both assemblies are signed

When "Local copy" of the ADOX-reference in Bar.exe is set to true as well, MS Build generates the warning 3181 - "Two or more files have the same target path" - which makes sense.

However, when I set "Local copy" of the ADOX-reference in Bar.exe to false, it compiles fine but upon startup of the application, an error is raised saying that the assembly Interop.ADOX could not be found and that the manifest definition of the assembly doesn't match the assembly reference.

I suppose I'm missing something rather simple here, but I was unable to solve my problem with Google. I'd be thankful for solutions or hints into the right direction :)

Cheers

Christian

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing the same assembly in both Foo.dll and Bar.exe (name AND version)? Where is Foo.dll referenced by Bar.exe? In a custom directory with its dependencies? What is the version of the Interop.ADOX.dll in this directory?

Comment: I checked again and yes, I'm referencing the same version of ADOX.dll (there is only one present on my machine). And I took the reference for Foo.dll directly from the bin directory of the Foo-project. In this directory, the Interop.ADOX.dll has Version 2.8, which looks fine to me, since I reference ADOX.dll with Version 2.8, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the EXE project didn't create the interop library.  But punt this problem.  Instead of having the EXE project reference ADO again, let it reference the interop library that was created by the DLL project.

Not exposing the ADO types in a public class would be the better solution.  ADO Ext is a utility bag, you should be able to encapsulate it well enough.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll try your suggestion with referencing the Interop-dll